# weird Safari crash. virus? malicious software?

Tags: safari, mojave, crash

since about a week there is a strange behaviour in my girlfriend's MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2018).

```
# uname -a
Darwin Air 18.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0: Thu Dec 20 20:46:53 PST 2018; root:xnu-4903.241.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

---

I have the supposition that this comes from me trying to get the Java Runtime Environment from this site: https://mac.filehorse.com/download-java-runtime/6018/

I want the JRE in order to run a .jar-file that allows me to control the mouse-pointer over WLAN. Which by the was I have not achieved yet...

---

**The symptoms**

Given that we mainly use this device to watch movies and series, this is also the only time when the weird crash happens. While streaming something (e.g. from Netflix) about one hour into the show - but always a different time - there is a crash. Safari closes and a strange software loads. It comes from "nowhere" and it has a different name every time. It has happened 3 or 4 times, once it was called "VirtualBasic", another time "GeneralLauncher", and another "DeluxeFocus". This "programs" appear as Safari extensions AND as Applications. I can't remove the extension without removing the software first. I am an iDevice-newbie so I have "deinstalled" the Applications by deleting it and emptying the Trash (is this the correct way to do it?). They appear in the Launchpad but they have no "x" to delete them.

The second time it happened I was very surprised, so I opened a terminal and ran `# find / -name "*eneral*aunche*"` and this is the output

```
/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/GeneralLaunch_2020-03-24-213804_USER-MacBook-Air.hang
/private/var/folders/4y/92hdyw2d0l3g6k9_7gg97gnc0000gn/T/com.q2wygenerallaunch
/private/var/folders/4y/92hdyw2d0l3g6k9_7gg97gnc0000gn/C/com.q2wygenerallaunch
/private/tmp/0B1ACE5D-1148-43D7-9D51-F71E51769C4D/CFFEEB77-DC26-4A97-89D3-61EAA536B8BC/GeneralLaunch.app
/private/tmp/0B1ACE5D-1148-43D7-9D51-F71E51769C4D/CFFEEB77-DC26-4A97-89D3-61EAA536B8BC/GeneralLaunch.app/Contents/MacOS/GeneralLaunch
/private/tmp/0B1ACE5D-1148-43D7-9D51-F71E51769C4D/CFFEEB77-DC26-4A97-89D3-61EAA536B8BC/GeneralLaunch.app/Contents/PlugIns/GeneralLaunch-extension.appex
/private/tmp/0B1ACE5D-1148-43D7-9D51-F71E51769C4D/CFFEEB77-DC26-4A97-89D3-61EAA536B8BC/GeneralLaunch.app/Contents/PlugIns/GeneralLaunch-extension.appex/Contents/MacOS/GeneralLaunch-extension
/Users/USER/Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/GeneralLaunch_F3FDB7C8-2CFF-5D8E-9247-9E40FBFE719C.plist
/Users/USER/Library/Application Scripts/com.q2wygenerallaunch
/Users/USER/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/GeneralLaunch_2020-03-24-213852_Emmas-MacBook-Air.crash
/Users/USER/Library/Group Containers/group.com.q2wygenerallaunch
/Users/USER/Library/Containers/com.q2wygenerallaunch
/Users/USER/Library/Containers/com.q2wygenerallaunch/Data/Library/Application Support/CrashReporter/GeneralLaunch_F3FDB7C8-2CFF-5D8E-9247-9E40FBFE719C.plist
/Users/USER/Library/Containers/com.q2wygenerallaunch/Data/Library/Preferences/shared.com.q2wygenerallaunch.plist
/Users/USER/Library/Containers/com.q2wygenerallaunch/Data/Library/Application Scripts/com.q2wygenerallaunch
/Users/USER/Applications/GeneralLaunch
```

The sneaky software seems to be everywhere! **I deleted all those files**, hoping for the best, but the crash happened again! Now with the other name. So, I did the same to track it down a bit:

```
# find / -name "*elux*ocu*"   
/private/var/folders/4y/92hdyw2d0l3g6k9_7gg97gnc0000gn/T/com.3xit0deluxefocus
/private/var/folders/4y/92hdyw2d0l3g6k9_7gg97gnc0000gn/C/com.3xit0deluxefocus
/private/tmp/EE53DC69-E4CD-41C3-B924-6F250F2819F9/2E683D7E-EB38-49AF-8463-0A16DD58FF5D/DeluxeFocus.app
/private/tmp/EE53DC69-E4CD-41C3-B924-6F250F2819F9/2E683D7E-EB38-49AF-8463-0A16DD58FF5D/DeluxeFocus.app/Contents/MacOS/DeluxeFocus
/private/tmp/EE53DC69-E4CD-41C3-B924-6F250F2819F9/2E683D7E-EB38-49AF-8463-0A16DD58FF5D/DeluxeFocus.app/Contents/PlugIns/DeluxeFocus-extension.appex
/private/tmp/EE53DC69-E4CD-41C3-B924-6F250F2819F9/2E683D7E-EB38-49AF-8463-0A16DD58FF5D/DeluxeFocus.app/Contents/PlugIns/DeluxeFocus-extension.appex/Contents/MacOS/DeluxeFocus-extension
/Users/USER/Library/Application Scripts/com.3xit0deluxefocus
/Users/USER/Library/Group Containers/group.com.3xit0deluxefocus
/Users/USER/Library/Containers/com.3xit0deluxefocus
/Users/USER/Library/Containers/com.3xit0deluxefocus/Data/Library/Preferences/shared.com.3xit0deluxefocus.plist
/Users/USER/Library/Containers/com.3xit0deluxefocus/Data/Library/Application Scripts/com.3xit0deluxefocus
/Users/USER/Library/Containers/com.3xit0deluxefocus/Data/Library/Caches/com.3xit0deluxefocus
/Users/USER/Applications/DeluxeFocus
/Users/USER/Applications/DeluxeFocus/DeluxeFocus.app
/Users/USER/Applications/DeluxeFocus/DeluxeFocus.app/Contents/MacOS/DeluxeFocus
/Users/USER/Applications/DeluxeFocus/DeluxeFocus.app/Contents/PlugIns/DeluxeFocus-extension.appex
/Users/USER/Applications/DeluxeFocus/DeluxeFocus.app/Contents/PlugIns/DeluxeFocus-extension.appex/Contents/MacOS/DeluxeFocus-extension
```

but I don't know what to do next...

---

what should I do? is the system infected with something? can it be removed? should I reinstall Safari? can I track this software down and deactivate it from running again?

Thanks

---

**Updates based on comments**
From the comment by Tetsujin I decided to try the freeware Malwarebytes and it did find 4 threats on the first scan:

[image: SearchSkilledData]

I have quarentined those threats. Let's see how things develop.
Based on that I decided to also run the following on terminal as an extended preventive measurement:

```
# find / -name "*earch*killed*"
/Library/Application Support/com.SearchSkilledDataDaemon
/Library/Application Support/com.SearchSkilledDataDaemon/SearchSkilledData
/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.SearchSkilledDataDaemon.plist
/Users/USER/Library/Application Support/com.SearchSkilledData
/Users/USER/Library/Application Support/com.SearchSkilledData/SearchSkilledData
/Users/USER/Library/LaunchAgents/com.SearchSkilledData.plist
```

Comment: Start with [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com)

Comment: You might want to get rid of `/Users/USER/Applications/GeneralLaunch` and `Users/USER/Applications/DeluxeFocus` if these are applications you don't remember installing yourself, and also remove `Library/LaunchDaemons/com.SearchSkilledDataDaemon.plist`and `/Users/USER/Library/LaunchAgents/com.SearchSkilledData.plist`, followed by a reboot.

Comment: Given that it’s mainly to watch Netflix, why not just wipe the drive and reinstall the OS?

Comment: And then download Java directly from https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp

Comment: @Allan hehe thaksn, but no...

Comment: @nohillside: I did that already. I deleted all the `"*eneral*aunch*"`files hoping for the best. but the software installs itself with a different name. it should be easy to remove malware in macOS. it is a UNIX system, right?

Comment: Right, but it's the same on all systems :-) If Malwarebytes alone doesn't help, look at the plists in /Library/Launch{Agents,Daemons} and ~/Library/Launch{Agents,Daemons} and get rid of whatever doesn't belong there. Ideally you boot into Recovery first to do this, to prevent any running malware from reinstalling itself.

Comment: I will give Malwarebytes some weeks to know the results. COVID-19-situation will allow intense testing